# Flutter application shows blank screen when running on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

`flutter doctor -v` shows no issues. 
Also I have updated the SDK and I've also done `flutter upgrade --force`
I cloned the project from here: https://github.com/llSourcell/How_to_Build_a_healthcare_startup
Please help me out!

Comment: tried `flutter run --enable-software-rendering` ?

Comment: Yes. Still I'm getting a white screen

Comment: does `flutter -v run --enable-software-rendering` show anything interesting?

Comment: Which Android Studio version you are using?

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. A friend of mine resolved the error for me.
Turns out it was a silly error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fetch the git repo with Android Studio v3.6.1

Dart: 2.7.0-dev2.1

Flutter: 1.12.13+hotfix.7 • channel stable •

I am able to open this project in Android Studio but not able to run. Maybe an issue with the code.

Try to upgrade Android Studio, Dart and Flutter versions. :)